# Laravel null object hasMany relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

SOLVED i should not have called out my attributes in the models. For some reason this was keeping it from working.

I have the following structure of two models, Listing and Image. Table Images has FK `listing_id` that references `id` on table Listing.

My Eloquent Model for Listing:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class Listing extends Model {

    protected $table = 'listings';
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $value;
    public $itemDescr;
    public $user_id;
    public $category_id;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'value',
        'itemDescr',
        'user_id',
        'category_id'
    ];

    /**
     * Return images
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image');
    }

}
```

My Eloquent Model for Image:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'images';
    protected $connection = 'mysql';

    public $id;
    public $imageType;
    public $title;
    public $filename;
    public $path;
    public $author_id;
    public $listing_id;
    public $user_id;
    public $size;
    public $width;
    public $height;


    protected $fillable = [
        'imageType',
        'title',
        'filename',
        'path',
        'author_id',
        'listing_id',
        'user_id',
        'size',
        'width',
        'height'
    ];

    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function listings()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Listing', 'listing_id');
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
/**
 * Return the full list of listings
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return string
 */

    public function itemList(Request $request)
    {
        $listings = Listing::with('images')->get();

        return $listings;

    }
```

I cannot seem to return my listing WITH the image objects -- they are always null. Here is a sample response:

> { id: 6, name: "rare listing item", value: "100", itemDescr: "this is a descr", user_id: 1, category_id: 6,
>   created_at: "2016-05-30 13:47:33", updated_at: "2016-05-30 13:47:33",
>   images: [ ] }

The database shows two images with listing_id of 6 for this particular item. I cannot figure out what could be wrong, I've tried nearly all suggestions. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a silly question, but is your Model at App/Models? Your code seems to be ok! It should work...

Comment: @Laerte yes. I dumped the sql its running, and I think my listing.id is going in as null to the statement, which is puzzling to me.

Comment: I think your relationships are backwards.  You say there are two images with listing id of 6.  That means listings can have many images.

Comment: @user3158900 this is true, but on Listing I have the method saying hasMany with Images? Is that incorrect?

Comment: Can you post the full code for the models, including the namespace? Also, have you tried to specify the keys to be used (eg: `return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Image', 'listing_id');`)?

Comment: @milz see full models. I have monkeyed with adding the FK/key to the return to no noticeable change :/

Comment: Try to remove those definition of attributes on your model, just curious why you do that? If you intended to make it visible then use `$visible` property.

Comment: I mean property definition of attributes such as `public $id`, `public $imageType`

Comment: public function listing()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Listing', 'listing_id, 'id');
}

Comment: @Rifki thank you that was why. My only excuse is that I come from java background. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel table columns and their values is held in `$attributes` property, Laravel uses `__get()` magic method to get the `$attributes` data. By defining `public $listing_id` as property on your model it just like telling Laravel: "Hey this is the `listing_id` and not the one that held `$attributes` property so please return this instead".

When you define the relationship:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Listing', 'listing_id', 'id');
```

The `public $listing_id` property will be returned which is the value is `null`. Remove those public property definition and it should be works.